# how to make a dataframe by changing condition on url?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, image, matplotlib

I have a dataframe, which contains many urls, is there a way i can make whenever it finds a specific url **"https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_normal.png"** it gives a value False, else true?

My dataframe:

| surname | image_url |
| --- | --- |
| First | [https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1557569949756899328/L4llDRNh_normal.jpg|](https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1557569949756899328/L4llDRNh_normal.jpg%7C) |
| Second | [https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_normal.png|](https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_normal.png%7C) |
| Third | https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1546820730616258560/wQfm-Ypn_normal.jpg |
| Fourth | https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_normal.png |

Expected:

| surname | value |
| --- | --- |
| First | True |
| Second | False |
| Third | True |
| Fourth | False |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `contains` which creates a boolean mask. By assigning it to `df['value']` you assign it to a new column, which gives you the desired result. This is even easier than creating a lambda function for it.

```
df['value'] = df.image_url.str.contains("https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_normal.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

```
url_pattern = "https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_normal.png"
df['value'] = df['image_url'].apply(lambda x: True if x == url_pattern else False)
```